# 3D columns plot using dataFrame and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I built a dataframe from uniprot file with the following columns:

```
(index(protein_id),length, organism, sequence,acidic, polar,hydrophobic,color,width)
```

The parameters `acidic`, `hydrophobic` and `polar` are percentages (i.e numbers between 1 to 100), `width` is between 0-1, and `color` is set of 4 numbers, e.g.: `(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`

I try to build 3d plot in the following manner:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


charge_sum = 0
display(df)
for index, record in prot_df.iterrows():
    xs=int(record['acidic'])
    ys=int(record['polar'])
    zs=int(record['hydrophobic'])
    cs=record['color']
    width=record['width']
    ax.bar(xs, ys, zs, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=width)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

But I get the following error:

```
>TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
><ipython-input-190-13bea2286c05> in <module>()
>     18     cs=record['color']
>     19     width=record['width']
>---> 20     ax.bar(xs, ys, zs, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=width)
>    21 
>    22 

>C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.pyc in >bar(self, left, height, zs, zdir, *args, **kwargs)
>  2392         patches = super(Axes3D, self).bar(left, height, *args, **kwargs)
>  2393 
>-> 2394         zs = _backports.broadcast_to(zs, len(left))
>   2395 
>   2396         verts = []
>
>TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Can someone help me get rid of this error?

Comment: the parameters: acidic, hydrophobic and polar are percentage(i.e numbers between 1 to 100), width is between 0-1, and color is set of 4 numbers, i.e: (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

Comment: If you want to plot individual bars, the arguments still have to be lists or arrays. Hence, `ax.bar(xs, ys, zs, ...)` should be `ax.bar([xs], [ys], [zs], ...)`.

Comment: I have removed my answer as it won't work for the data in the form you describe - @ImportanceOfBeingErnest comment should work for getting rid of the error - can edit your question if it's not the plot you want.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It seems that when I give it lists, I get the following error: TypeError: alpha must be a float or None

Comment: so what is `width` then? Find out via `print(type(width))`.